# In Microsoft SQL Server, how to keep distinct rows for only a specific value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of events. I would like to eliminate certain values which appear multiple times, e.g.

```
CreateDate  EventCode
------------------------
2023-03-20  EMA
2023-03-21  EMD
2023-03-22  EMD
2023-03-22  EMF
2023-03-23  EMI
2023-03-24  EMI
```

The `EMI` must only appear once and only the first EMI from 23 March. Other duplicates like EMD can remain.

So the result should be

```
CreateDate  EventCode
------------------------
2023-03-20  EMA
2023-03-21  EMD
2023-03-22  EMD
2023-03-22  EMF
2023-03-23  EMI
```

A simple group by will eliminate the duplicate EMDs

Here my attempt with sample SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Movements

CREATE TABLE #Movements 
(
    CreateDate datetime2,
    EventCode nvarchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO #Movements (CreateDate, EventCode) VALUES ('2023-03-20', 'EMA')
INSERT INTO #Movements (CreateDate, EventCode) VALUES ('2023-03-21', 'EMD')
INSERT INTO #Movements (CreateDate, EventCode) VALUES ('2023-03-22', 'EMD')
INSERT INTO #Movements (CreateDate, EventCode) VALUES ('2023-03-22', 'EMF')
INSERT INTO #Movements (CreateDate, EventCode) VALUES ('2023-03-23', 'EMI')
INSERT INTO #Movements (CreateDate, EventCode) VALUES ('2023-03-24', 'EMI')

SELECT * FROM #Movements

SELECT EventCode 
FROM #Movements
GROUP BY EventCode
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` but no aggregate functions used? Do you simply want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT EventCode FROM #Movements will remove the duplicate EMI but also the duplicate EMD. So same results as GROUP BY

Comment: I know, but why? You can also use UNION or INTERSECT to get distinct results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle the cases where the EMI can be found 2 times or more :

```
select t.*
from #Movements t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT EventCode, MIN(CreateDate) as CreateDate
  FROM #Movements
  WHERE EventCode = 'EMI'
  GROUP BY EventCode
) s on s.EventCode = t.EventCode and t.CreateDate > s.CreateDate
where s.CreateDate is null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JuUllB0t)

Answer (score 1):

It can be just

```
SELECT distinct case EventCode    
                when 'EMI' then min(CreateDate) over(partition by EventCode) 
                else CreateDate end CreateDate, EventCode 
FROM #Movements
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to group by both columns, but null out `CreateDate` for rows where `EventCode = 'EMI'`. Then take `MIN(CreateDate)` for those rows instead.

```sql
SELECT
  ISNULL(CASE WHEN EventCode <> 'EMI' THEN CreateDate END, MIN(CreateDate)) AS CreateDate,
  EventCode
FROM #Movements
GROUP BY
  EventCode,
  CASE WHEN EventCode <> 'EMI' THEN CreateDate END;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/I_etpYJU)